# iphone uitableview load next detail view from segmented control like mail app

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi i have added a segmented control to a detailview header in a subview of a uitableview table and used images for up and down to create a up and down control like the one in mail.app. the buttons are working fine.

im after some advice on how to get rid of that items view and reload the next item without having to go back to the main uitableview.

im sure i saw some code on this website doing exactly that but i cant find it!

can anyone point me in right direction or help?

thanks

Comment: Why not just retrieve the next/previous item from your model and replace the current detail items with the new ones? It seems like that's what the mail app is doing. You don't necessarily have to get rid of the current view or pop it from the nav controller stack.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. any tips on how to do that. how do i call - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath which is in my ViewController from the detailViewController with an updated row?

Comment: to clarify what i'm keen to do is have the main table keep up. so for example in mail if you use the down button to go down lots of emails when you go up a level it is on the right selection that you have just moved not the one you originally chose. also you can see the highlight disappear from it.